# How can I get to the children deep level?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this case there are two walls.
Each wall have 4 children and each of the 4 children have a cube child that I want to color.

[image: Children hierarchy]

This code color only one of the 4 children of each wall and not all the 4 :

```cs
private void ColorWalls()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < walls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (randomColors)
        {
            walls[i].transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color
                = GetRandomColour32();
        }
        else
        {
            walls[i].transform.GetChild(0).transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[i];
        }
    }
}
```

How can I loop more deep to color all the 4 cubes of each wall ?

Comment: One way is to Assign all walls a "coloringScript" and find the object of the type "coloringscript" via GetComponentsInChildren, then set the color to each component found.

Comment: My bad I forgot that I gave each wall(Cube)(grandchildren) a tag name "Wall" while the tag "Walls" present all the Walls prefabs I'm creating.  So if I have 3 Walls than there are 12 grand children cubes and because they have tagged as "Wall" all I had to do is  : var childrenWalls = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Wall"); loop on the childrenWalls get only the first child (0) and change the color/s

Comment: Never mind I messed it for nothing.  Maybe I should delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way is `GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>` . But in case that there are `Renderer` other than wall would be in the hierarchy. There are at least 2 ways to do this:

1. add tag to wall gameobject.

[image]

Then use `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` to get all the gameobjects.

2. add custom `MonoBehaviour` to wall gameobject, let us call it `Wall`.

Then you can call `GetComponentsInChildren<Wall>()` at the root gameobject.

Answer (score 1):

https://answers.unity.com/questions/799429/transformfindstring-no-longer-finds-grandchild.html

This will help you find the deep child of a transform. But if it is just the components that you're looking for without the need for the hierarchy info, you can go with what's been suggested in @rootpanthera's comment.